# "New": Too many arguments

Tags: vb.net, forms, overriding

I made a "custom" form as seen below. When I say:

```
Dim nSplash As New frmSplash(nBitmap)
```

It is telling me that there are "**too many arguments for Public Sub New**".

I do not see why it is mocking about it.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace AlphaWindow

Public Class frmSplash

    Inherits Form

    Public Sub New(ByRef uBitmap As Bitmap)

        Me.Size = uBitmap.Size
        Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

        APIHelp.ShowTopmost(Me)

        Me.SelectBitmap(uBitmap)

    End Sub

 (...)

' Class to assist with Win32 API calls
Class APIHelp

    Private Const SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE As Integer = 4
    Private Const HWND_TOPMOST As Integer = -1

 (...)

End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing wrong, using your code I am able to New up your frmSplash with no errors, You should add InitializeComponents to your Constructor though

Comment: @Mark Hall How do you instantiate the form? I do it by         Dim nBitmap As New Bitmap(Me.[GetType]().[Module].Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("AlphaWindow.Channel9.png"))
        Dim nSplash As New frmSplash(nBitmap) Do you see any flaw here?

Comment: When I remove the Namespace AlphaWindow, it works fine, but I would like to keep the Namespace. Can anyone help?

Comment: As an aside, why are you passing uBitmap ByRef?

Comment: Does your form have a `.Designer.vb` file? When a class is split between two files you have to add the namespace to both files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the Namespace, but when a namespace is included, the form has to be called by "Namespace.Form" instead of just "Form".